# How to Determine typical rate of progression with haphazardly collected data?

Tags: regression, random-effects-model

We are studying various parameters in extant patient records. Some patients were tested once. Some patients many times. All at different ages. but all have the same disease.

We would like to use the age vs. parameter data to determine the typical course of progressive deterioration in our disease population. What is the right approach to doing this, mindful that individuals may progress at different rates, but also that there must be some "typical" course?  SPSS preferred.

I'm trying to solve this with a random effects "MIXED" model, but if that's right, I can't quite figure it out.

Thanks!

EDIT

In an attempt to clarify the above, let me add the following:

We have patients who visit us at all different ages; we track many of their characteristics, from biometric ones like height or weight, to functional ones like visual acuity.

Because patient visits are not part of a planned study, we don't have uniform sampling, and sometimes have cross-sectional data (when a patient had a characteristic measured once) and other times longitudinal data (when we have several visits from the same patient).

When data are sampled in this kind of haphazard way, I am unsure how to generate norms and, ideally, prediction limits for the course of a characteristic of interest (AKA, a parameter).  For example, in patients with an inherited blinding disorder, it would be nice to know what the typical pattern of vision loss is as a function of age.

EDIT 2

I think I have achieved something close to the desired outcome in MATLAB.  I created a table, T, with 4 columns.  The first is a categorical subject identifier (in my case the patient medical record number, MRN).  The second is a scaler, the age at test (AAT) in years.  The third is a categorical indicator of the eye that was tested (left vs right), and the fourth is a scaler, the parameter of interest, visual acuity (VA).

To perform the analysis, I ran

```
lme = fitlme(T, 'VA ~ 1 + AgeAtTest * Eye + (1 | MRN)', 'FitMethod', 'REML')
```

This produces coefficients for Intercept, AAT, Eye and AAT:Eye, as well as P values.  Neither Eye nor AAT:Eye are significant, but the intercept and AAT are.  Thus, I now have a "typical" rate of progression for the disease from the AAT parameter.  This is a start.  I still am not certain this is right (although it looks pretty reasonable) nor do I have any idea how to do the equivalent in SPSS, which I would like to know.

Comment: What is "age vs. parameter data"?  Parameters are estimated from data.

Comment: Perhaps "observation" would have been a better term.  But if we have patients who visit us at all different ages, we track many of their characteristics.  From biometric ones like their height or weight, to functional ones like their visual acuity.

Comment: At the outset I was thinking your use of "parameter" was in the sense of a "characteristic," but then in the edit you started using the latter word, too.  Would I be correct to assume you treat these words synonymously?  If not, then what distinction are you making?  (The comment by @Peter was directed at experienced statisticians who have been taught to use "parameter" to refer to hypothetical properties of a probability model and other words like "characteristics" or "observations" to refer to the things you measure and record.)

Comment: I don't think they're synonymous, but they are certainly overlapping.  In this case, I just mean data point.  For example, visual acuity.